# XPath works standalone, but does not work when put in a web app

Tags: java, xml, xpath, expression

I am looking to parse the XML, With the help of xpath expression I want to bring in all the node values whose node name is AuditRecord. Surprisingly I can do this in a standalone application but same code fails in the application.  I didnt even change the XML. I am using the same XML file in the standalone application and web application I can see results in standlone application but I get 0 nodelist size when I try the same thing in webapplication.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale; 
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class TestXmlNode {
private static final String TEST_XML = "C:/test.xml";
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    try {
        //XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        /*System.out.println("*************************");
        String expression = "//AuditRecord/DateTimeStamp";;
        System.out.println("*************************");
        System.out.println(expression);
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument,     XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("Nodelist size"+nodeList.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            String date = nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
          System.out.println("Date after split     "+date.split("T")[0]);
            Date thedate = convertStringToDate(date);
            Date  todate = convertStringToDate("2014-01-01"); 
            System.out.println("XML todate"+todate.toString()); 
        if(thedate.after(todate))
            System.out.println("-------------------------->"+ thedate.toString());
        }*/
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(TEST_XML));
      DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      org.w3c.dom.Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);
      XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
      XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
      XPathExpression xPathExpr = xpath.compile("//AuditRecord/DateTimeStamp/text()");
      Object result = xPathExpr.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
      print(result);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}   
public static void print(Object result){
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  System.out.println(i+" "+nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
}
}

}
```

Comment: Does your web setup use the same jars?

Comment: Fro XML parsing i am using JAVAX classes . i dont need special jars to do

Answer (score 0):

Your web app probably doesn't have access to C:/test.xml as web apps generally aren't allowed to access the file system directly.

Comment: I should be getting file not found exception, more over i have converted the XML content as string to see the content of the XML. i can see the content as well

Comment: Not necessarily.   Try adding a catch block for Exception to see what's happening.

Comment: it s not entering the exception block

Answer (score 0):

The presence of xmlparserv-2.0.jar in the classpath is issue, which does not allow to apply xpath expression. Any idea on how to move on

Comment: The issue is with the Namespace prefix, as the default namesapce has no prefix, as a reason its not applying xpath filter.